# showlabels package and segmented document

Tags: cross-referencing, input, showlabels

I have a segmented document, namely I import packages through `\input{Preambule}`.
However, the `showlabels` package does nothing when called in the Preambule file, but works when called in the main.

Does anyone knows anything about that, or has in mind another package to show labels that works when called in through an `input` command?

Comment: `\input` has virtually no affect on tex macros, it is exactly the same as just copying the contents of the file into eh main document. Please always include a complete small example document so people can reproduce the problem and test answers.

Comment: As usual, your wise advices brought results: neither `input` nor `showlabels` were at fault. Loading in the preamble file I tried to sort the packages used by categories and ended up loading showlabels before `amsmath`. It would appear they don't play nice with each other.

Comment: You could always try `showkeys` instead:-)

Comment: You could post a self answer, just to close the loop on this question, thanks.

Comment: I saw you were the author of showkeys, but I modified (kinda heavily) the output of showlabels so I'll stick to it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by @David-Carlisle, not a problem from `input` nor (not really) `showlabels`: just a conflit with `amsmath`. Always load `showlabels` after `amsmath`. Always.

Comment: after further reading, amsmath redefines latex's numbering macro, and showlabels patches the numbering macro (whether it's latex's or amsmath's). Hence why no error message were printed :/